# Open hours in restaurant, mergin array data with same value but different key

Tags: arrays, grouping, dynamic

I have almost search the complete internet for an answer to my question.
I havent found anything yet solving my problem.

I want to create a open hours list for restaurant dynamicaly from data pulled out of my database.

At the moment i'm doing this:

Pulling out data, and put them into an array.
Assign day as key, and open / close as open / close values from the database.

My code below:

```
// opening hours
public static function opening_hours($var)
{
    // sql
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE _id = '$var'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    // arrays
    $rows['mon'] = array(open => $data['10'], close => $data['11']);
    $rows['tue'] = array(open => $data['12'], close => $data['13']);
    $rows['wen'] = array(open => $data['14'], close => $data['15']);
    $rows['thu'] = array(open => $data['16'], close => $data['17']);
    $rows['fri'] = array(open => $data['18'], close => $data['19']);
    $rows['sat'] = array(open => $data['20'], close => $data['21']);
    $rows['sun'] = array(open => $data['22'], close => $data['23']);

    // days
    //$days = array(mon, tue, wen, thu, fri, sat, sun);

    // print
    // print '<pre>'. print_r($rows, true).'</pre>';


    foreach ($rows as $key => $value)
    {

        // key
        if($key == 'mon') { $key = 'Man'; }
        else if($key == 'tue') { $key = 'Tir'; }
        else if($key == 'wen') { $key = 'Ons'; }
        else if($key == 'thu') { $key = 'Tor'; }
        else if($key == 'fri') { $key = 'Fre'; }
        else if($key == 'sat') { $key = 'Lør'; }
        else if($key == 'sun') { $key = 'Søn'; }

        // value
        if($value['open'] == 'clo' && $value['close'] == 'clo')
        {
            $value['open'] = 'Lukket';
            $value['close'] = '';
        }


        // other


        // print
        $r = '<div>';
        $r .= $key;
        $r .= ': ';
        $r .= $value['open'];
        $r .= ' - ';
        $r .= $value['close'];  
        $r .= '</div>';

        echo $r;



    }

}
```

The output is:

Man: 16:00 - 22:00

Tir: 16:00 - 22:00

Ons: 16:00 - 22:00

Tor: 16:00 - 22:00

Fre: 14:00 - 23:30

Lør: 16:00 - 22:00

Søn: Lukket -

**My problem is, i want the values where the open and close timeset area the same, to be merged.**

In this case the output should be:

Man - Tors and Lør: 16:00 - 22:00

Fre: 14:00 - 23:30

Søn: Lukket

I have absolutely no clue on how to do this.

Looking forward to your help.

Thanks!